# histogram_quantile isn't plotting correctly for multiple labels

Tags: monitoring, prometheus, grafana, promql

I tried to plot using `histogram_quantile` with Prometheus with sum on two labels, i.e.

`histogram_quantile(0.9, sum(rate(grpc_request_duration_seconds_bucket{service="$service"}[$interval])) by (le, grpc_method))`

The resulting plot was not the same as me manually making a separate plot for each individual value of `grpc_method`:

`histogram_quantile(0.9, sum(rate(grpc_request_duration_seconds_bucket{service="$service",grpc_method="GetGridFile"}[$interval])) by (le, grpc_method))`

and

`histogram_quantile(0.9, sum(rate(grpc_request_duration_seconds_bucket{service="$service",grpc_method="PostAgvState"}[$interval])) by (le, grpc_method))`

[image]

Comment: Were you able to get an answer for this?